# _this.store.getState is not a function when testing react component with enzyme and mocha

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm trying to test a React component with enzyme and mocha as follows

```
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai'
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'

import MyComponent from 'myComponent'

chai.use(chaiEnzyme())
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const store = {
    id: 1
  }
  it ('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />, {context: {store: store}})
  })
})
```

haven't actually written the test as it fails at the declaration of wrapper

Error message: TypeError: _this.store.getState is not a function

No idea what the problem is and cant find anything addressing this!

Any help would be great!

Comment: You actually need to pass redux-store. You can't just create a constant and pass it as store.

Answer (score 7):

This error means that store can't get the state correctly.
I would recommend mocking the store using [redux-mock-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store)
and import configureStore

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
```

then mock the state by doing this

```
    const initialState = { id: 1 };
    const mockStore = configureStore();
```

and you can continue by wrapping your component with provider

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; // add this to the top of your file

const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
    <MyComponent />
  </Provider>,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, shouldn't `chai.user()` be `chai.use()` in your code example?